# Debugging Azure: window popup says The web browser can not be started

Tags: azure, azure-debugger

I have a web application asp.net to deploy to Windows Azure. This application contains one web role. I try to run it on local first. But when debugging, I catch this error from VS2010: "Window Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
The Web Browser can not be started. To resolve this problem, you must restart Windows."

I have restarted windows several times, but there was no luck.![enter image description here][1]
I've search so hard to find the solution for this problem but there's nothing seems work for me. I'm a newbie in Windows Azure, it's really a big trouble with me. Please help me! Thanks a lot. Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

There could be two problems:

1. Problem with your IIS settings: It is possible that there is a problem with your IIS in your machine which could not be restarted when VS2010, wants to run it.

   - To verify it what you can do it launch your Web Role using "View in Browser" setting and see if your Web Role can run in IIS, you will see the web role started in a URL as http:\localhost:XXXXX and that would be the first step to resolved.
2. Problem will your Windows Azure SDK which could not launch the WebBrowser to run in IIS

   - If you don't have problem in this step #1, then it is possible that Windows Azure SDK has some problem trying to start your IIS from external process and this could be caused by corrupted SDK installation or any other reason.

If that is the case try:

1. remove all Windows Azure SDK components from your machine.
2. Restart the machine, [Install Azure SDK from here for VS2010](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/downloads/)
3. After SDK install, restart the VS2010 in admin mode and try created a hello world webrole and see what happens.